# How to pass array value using AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, objective-c, paypal, afnetworking

Now i am working in paypal recurring integration using APIS, i am facing request format problem in the following API.
How to send request format as same as fellow.

```
curl -v -k -X PATCH 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-plans/P-94458432VR012762KRWBZEUA' \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer <Access-Token>" \
    -d '[
        {
            "path": "/",
            "value": {
                "state": "ACTIVE"
            },
            "op": "replace"
        }
    ]'
```

So far i have tried following code

```
 NSDictionary *valueDic = @{@"state":@"ACTIVE"};
    NSDictionary *parametersDic = @{@"path":@"/",@"value":valueDic,@"op":@"replace"};
    NSMutableArray *parameterArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [parameterArray addObject:parametersDic];

    NSString *finalyToken = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"Bearer %@",strAccessToken];
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:finalyToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json+patch" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"application/json"];

    NSString *urlPatch = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-plans/%@",creditCardId];
    [manager PATCH:urlPatch parameters:parameterArray success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){
         NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
        [self recurringCreateBillingAgreement];
    }failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
       NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
```

i have created request format like above

```
(
{
    op = replace;
    path = "/";
    value =     {
        state = ACTIVE;
    };
}
)
```

But,I am getting following error

```
Error: Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: internal server error (500)" UserInfo=0x177155d0 {com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x1755c9b0> { URL: https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-plans/P-1DT55351E261652436BZHSLA } { status code: 500, headers {
    "CORRELATION-ID" = 6bf7cbf78bb16;
    Connection = "close, close";
    "Content-Length" = 196;
    "Content-Type" = "text/xml;charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Thu, 07 Apr 2016 11:19:08 GMT";
    "PROXY_SERVER_INFO" = "host=slcsbplatformapiserv3001.slc.paypal.com;threadId=368";
    "Paypal-Debug-Id" = "6bf7cbf78bb16, 6bf7cbf78bb16";
    Server = Apache;
    "Set-Cookie" = "X-PP-SILOVER=name%3DSANDBOX3.API.1%26silo_version%3D1880%26app%3Dplatformapiserv%26TIME%3D742524503; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly, X-PP-SILOVER=; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT";
    Vary = Authorization;
} }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-plans/P-1DT55351E261652436BZHSLA, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: internal server error (500), com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<3c6e7331 3a584d4c 4661756c 7420786d 6c6e733a 6e73313d 22687474 703a2f2f 6378662e 61706163 68652e6f 72672f62 696e6469 6e67732f 78666f72 6d617422 3e3c6e73 313a6661 756c7473 7472696e 6720786d 6c6e733a 6e73313d 22687474 703a2f2f 6378662e 61706163 68652e6f 72672f62 696e6469 6e67732f 78666f72 6d617422 3e6a6176 612e6c61 6e672e4e 756c6c50 6f696e74 65724578 63657074 696f6e3c 2f6e7331 3a666175 6c747374 72696e67 3e3c2f6e 73313a58 4d4c4661 756c743e>, NSUnderlyingError=0x1757d4c0 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/xml"}
```

Comment: The above error resolve used this line of code  `NSString* jsonString = @"[{\"path\": \"/\",\"value\": {\"state\": \"ACTIVE\"},\"op\": \"replace\"}]";
    NSData *postBodyData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [jsonString UTF8String] length:[jsonString length]];`

Answer (score 0):

You need to send JSON string as one parameter.
You can create JSON string of your array as below.

```
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameterArray options:0 error:nil];
NSString* jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

`parameterArray` will be your array

Now use `jsonString` as value of one of your parameters, so you can send it to server.